# Spring mvc app with embedded Tomcat server error: "Unable to determine web application context.xml"

Tags: spring, tomcat, jar

I'm working on a Spring MVC App. It used to work on a Tomcat server where Intellij would deploy it as a war. Now I would like to change it to a Uber-jar with an embedded Tomcat server. I tried several tutorials, but I can't get it to work. At the moment I'm receiving this error message:

> c:\Projects\private\WMCase\target>java -jar wmcase-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   mar 29, 2020 1:19:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat getWebappConfigFileFromWar
>   WARNING: Unable to determine web application context.xml [c:\Projects\private\WMCase\target\src\main]
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Projects\private\WMCase\target\src\main (System nie mo?e odnale?? okre?lonej ?cie?ki)

Followed by several **LifecycleException**s ( Failed to start component ) that originate from:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Projects\private\WMCase\target\src\main] is not valid

Here is my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wojto</groupId>
  <artifactId>wmcase</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>WMcase Maven Webapp</name>

  <!--  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->



    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.30</tomcat.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- MySQL, jdbc driver -->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bodaj do connectin pool? -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP, JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Embedded Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.M6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>wmcase</finalName>


                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.wojto.wmcase.application.Application</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

And the **main** method:

```
package com.wojto.wmcase.application;

import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

import java.io.File;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String webAppDirLocation = "src/main/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        //Set Port #
        tomcat.setPort(8080);

        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/wmcase", new File(webAppDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

}
```

I'm getting pretty desperate and thinking of migrating the app to spring-boot.

Comment: Did you had any luck with this?

Comment: Not really, It's a side project and didn't have time to work more on it. I'll probably migrate it to spring boot if I have any time to work on it.